# How can I draw a concave corner rectangle in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I draw a concave corner rectangle in WPF?

Answer (score 3):

You can create this by Path Operation under Expression blend (Menu - Object-> Path operations) I have created a Path by subtracting four ellipse against a rectangle.

the Path.Data for a concave rectangle is given below, @Kent Fredric logic in the previous answer will be helpful to implement one.

[image]

```
M17.200002,0L120.4,0 120.4,2.3066998E-06C120.4,6.7378696,128.10079,12.200001,137.60001,12.200001L137.60001,85.400003C128.10077,85.400003,120.4,90.862138,120.4,97.6L17.200002,97.6C17.200002,90.862151,9.4993697,85.400003,0,85.400003L0,12.199999C9.4993663,12.200015,17.200002,6.7378725,17.200002,0z
```

See the blog post here http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2008/11/concave-cornered-rectangle-blend-tip.html

Another way to get this is to create a WPF Custom Shape like bellow

```
public class ConcaveRectangle:System.Windows.Shapes.Shape
```

Comment: Thank you,
 I asked this question on a different forum and got the same solution by using the Path function in WPF.

Answer (score 2):

```
do you mean a rectangle with concave corners?, ie: 
     ____________________
    |                    |
  __|                    |__
 |                          |
 |                          |
 |                          |
 |__                      __|
    |                    |
    |____________________|
```

Given a rectangle of dimension  `w x h` with corner radius `r`
There are 4 corners:

```
A :  0,0
B :  w,0
C :  w,h
D :  0,h
```

There is an implicit minimum size of

```
w = 2r
h = 2r
```

There are 4 Circle Centers, `A,B,C,D`

And there's thus a grid of edge points:

```
(0,0)--(0+r,0)---(w-r,0)---(w,0)
|                              |
(0,0+r)                  (w,0+r)
|                              |
|                              |
(0,h-r)                  (w,h-r)
|                              |
(0,h)--(0+r,h)---(w-r,h)---(w,h)
```

Then its merely a case of computing the arc from one point to another.

Answer (score 0):

I should point out that if it's concave, the four sides aren't both identical and straight; thus it's not a rectangle.  But I digress.